# Writing common alert service using ionic2/angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to show alert messages in every page. how do I write the common service using angular2/ionic2 to achieve this?

**Right now I am writing showAlert() function in every '.ts' file in the following way.**

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Alerts` are related to the views and not with *application data*, I think that instead of using a *service* for doing that, we could just use `Events`. The idea is to add that code in your `app.ts` file like this:

```
constructor(public events: Events, private alertCtrl: AlertController, ...) {

    // Your code...

    // Subscribe to the event 'alert:presented'
    events.subscribe('alert:presented', (alertData) => {
      this.showAlert(alertData[0]);
    });  
}

// This method will show the alerts with the name sent as parameter
public showAlert(name: string) {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, ' + name + ', just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Then, you can present an Alert from any other view, by just doing

```
constructor(public events: Events, ...) { 

}

public yourMethod() {
  this.events.publish('alert:presented', 'Obi wan Kenobi');
}
```